# Regular Expression

Tags: visualforce, javascript, regular-expressions

Can someone please let me know the regular expressions for below matching case. I am implementing this validation on Visualforce page.

UserName – 6 symbols, no special characters. No numbers in first position

Password – 9 characters, should present at least one capital letter, one number or special symbol

I want to match the username and password based on the regular expression.

Comment: This appears a pure JS question, for which you'll find more experts, in general or JS specific sites such as stackoverflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For user name the following Regex should work:

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{5}$
```

- [a-zA-Z] ==> First character any alphabet but not digit.
- [a-zA-Z0-9]{5} == > Next five character any alphabet or digit.

For the password:

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]{9,}$
```

- (?=.*[A-Z]) ==> Should have atleast one Capital character
- (?=.*\d) ==> Should have atleast one digit.
- (?=.*[$@$!%*?&]) ==> Should have atleast one of these special
  characters
- [A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&] ==> Password must be comprised of any of these
  characters.
- {9} ==> length 9 characters.